# If the given system has at least one solution. Then, which of the following is(are) true?

Tags: linear-algebra

suppose $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb R.$ Consider the following system of equations. $$x+y+z=\alpha,x+\beta y+z=\gamma, x+y+\alpha z=\beta.$$ If this system has atleast one solution. Then, which of the following is(are) true?

(A)If $\alpha=1$ then $\gamma=1$

(B)If $\beta=1$ then $\gamma=\alpha$

(C)If $\beta \neq 1$ then $\alpha=1$

(D) If $\gamma=1$ then $\alpha=1$

The Augmented matrix corresponding to the given system,

$\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1  & \alpha \\
  1 & \beta & 1 &\gamma  \\
  1&1&\alpha &\beta
\end{bmatrix}$

After $R_2\to R_2-R_1$ and $R_3\to R_3-R_1$

We get $\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1  & \alpha \\
  0& \beta-1 & 0 &\gamma-\alpha  \\
  0&0&\alpha-1 &\beta-\alpha
\end{bmatrix}$

I can deduce, if $\alpha-1=0$ and $\beta\neq \alpha$. Solution Inconsistent ($\because 0.z\neq \text{non-zero number}$). This is not the case. Possible cases for at least one solutions are $\alpha-1=0$ and $\beta= \alpha$ and $\alpha-1 \neq 0$ and $\beta- \alpha \in \mathbb R$

Another possible case for inconsistent system, $\beta=1$ and $\gamma \neq \alpha$. But the options are in $p \implies q$ form. I am not able to choose the most correct answer. Please help me to opt for a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that (A) and (B) are true, while (C) and (D) are false. To show that (A) is true, I would suggest assuming that $\alpha=1,$ and try to prove that $\gamma=1.$ A similar direct approach works for (B). For (C), I would suggest assuming that $\beta\ne 1$ and $\alpha\ne 1,$ then continuing to row-reduce and show that the system is still consistent. For (D), a similar approach works, so long as $\beta\ne 1.$

Comment: I can conclude, if the options f the form $p$ and $q$. But the options are in $p\implies q$ form. How did you prove it by contradiction?

Comment: For (C) suppose $\beta \neq 1$ and $\alpha \neq 1$ where will I get contradiction?($p $ and ~q)

Comment: Oh, dear.... I really shouldn't try to do logic before I've had my coffee. Rather, you've shown that $\alpha=1$ implies $\beta=1,$ which is equivalent to showing that $\beta\ne 1$ implies $\alpha\ne 1.$ However, this isn't the same as showing that (C) is false, since the system can still have a solution if $\beta=1.$ Apologies! I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: How do (A) is true? Assuming $\alpha=1$, then $\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1  & 1\\
  0& \beta-1 & 0 &\gamma-1 \\
  0&0&0 &\beta-1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: But if $\beta \neq 1$ still the system is inconsistent. whether $\gamma=1$ or not.

Comment: But the system *is* consistent, so $\beta=1,$ and so $\gamma=1.$

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much for bringing my thought on the given condition

Comment: You're welcome!